# C++14 Function returns array of objects although copy constructor is deleted

Tags: c++, c++14, decltype-auto

from the old C++98 i am aware, that return types a copied (by value) if not mentioned in the function declaration/definition otherwise with the address operator '&'.

Now i am playing around with the concepts of auto and decltype to let the compiler determin the return type. In an example i worte a `class A`  where with exception of the default ctor any other ctors are deleted (class A is taken from a real project - and i investigate some issues). An object of the class A is contructed together with an etl::array (Embedded template library, Array created on the ***stack*** with ***fixed size***), see example code below.

```
#include <etl/array.h>
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A(std::uint8_t val) : _val(val){}
    A(A const&) = delete;      // copy delete
    A& operator=(A&) = delete; // copy assign delete
    A(A&&) = default;          // move default
    A& operator=(A&&) = delete;// move assign delete
    ~A() = default;
    void whoAmI(){std::cout << " I am A! " << std::endl;}
private:
    std::uint8_t _val;
};

decltype(auto) X(std::uint8_t val) {
  return etl::array<A,1>{A{val}};
}

int main()
{
    decltype(auto) x = X(5U);
    for (auto& it : x) {
      it.whoAmI();
    }
}
```

I would expect, that the etl::array will be copied in the main() routine and assigned to the local variable x. I would not expect to have a copy of A in the array, due to the deleted copy ctor. However, the code compiles and i am able to call the function on the element of the etl::array. I cannot understand why this is working and why it is compiling at all? And I wonder what type `decltype(auto)` finally is. I have chosen `decltype(auto)` because of Scott-Meyers Item 2 and Item 3. To item 3, i am not sure to have a complete understanding on the decltype topic..

When I step through the code it works fine, leaving me pussled behind..

Any help on this topic is highly appreciated!

---

Thank you very much for your help, it is enlightening to me.
Now i finally know why it's working :-D - you made my day!

Comment: it'll be using the move constructor, did you mean to delete that too?

Comment: Returning a prvalue without any conversions is mandatory copy elision, which is allowed even in the absence of copy/move semantics. See the linked question for more information.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik There might be a good dupe for this, but the target you've added is not appropriate. The copy-elision doesn't apply directly to the OP's question since they have a move-constructor, and are compiling with C++14. The code doesn't actually compile without defaulting the move-constructor, and that's not really addressed in the target.

Comment: As mentioned in my last comment, I don't think the target is appropriate, so I'm voting to reopen the question.

Comment: Except that copy elision is exactly what's happening here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik No, it's using the move-constructor. `delete`ing it makes the code [fail](https://godbolt.org/z/5556Td). Non-mandatory copy-elision is not allowed when the necessary constructors are not available (it just means they may not get *used*).

Comment: Fair enough, reopened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`decltype(auto)` is used to determine the type and the value category of an expression. When used as a return type, it lets the function decide what the returned value type should be, based on the expression in the return statement. In this example, since you are using a temporary in the returned expression, it will deduce to an rvalue.

In this declaration:

```
decltype(auto) x = X(5U);
```

the syntax is copy-initialization, which has the effect of initializing the variable `x` from the expression `X(5U)`. You have a defaulted move-constructor, and the compiler uses this constructor to initialize `x` from the rvalue returned from `X`.

Note that from C++17, due to mandatory copy-elision, you could even delete the move constructor, and the code is still valid, since there is no constructor needed to initialize `x`.